# Cannot get sum of all similar rows in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a booking table of student which list all the teacher he has booked. 
Structure is as follows:

```
Teacher Name    Date     start_time   end_time     hour       rate
```

Now I want to list the booking as follows I want to calculate total rate which the student paid to every teacher and total of number of hours booked for each teacher. 
I want to do it with one query I'm using php with mysql.

```
 S. No  Teacher's Name         Date      Class Start time    Class End Time   Hours    Rate

1.       Amit Kumar           5-10-2019      8:00 A.M.          9:00 A.M.       1      2000.00
2.       Amit Kumar           6-10-2019      9:00 A.M.         10:00 A.M.       1      5000.00
Total                                                                           2      7000.00

3.       Pawan Kumar          7-10-2019      10:00 A.M.        11:00 A.M.       1      4000.00
4.       Pawan Kumar          8-10-2019      7:00 A.M.          8:00 A.M.       1      4000.00
Total                                                                           2      8000.00
...
...
```

Comment: What are the types of the `start_time` and `end_time` columns?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : It is varchar(50) NULL it is saved like 08:15:00

Comment: Did you really store `11:00 A.M.` in that column, or did you instead store `11:00:00`?

Comment: saved like 11:00:00 that is have converted with php function but my main issue is the calculation part of same teacher total amount paid and no of hours booked.

Comment: Your life would get a lot easier if you'd use a datetime type for start_time and end_time, then they could be easily datediff'd to give the number of hours. Don't even go for separating them into "a date" and "a time" - Anywhere you ever want to store dates and times, use a datetime not a varchar. Using a pair of datetime allows your class to start at 11pm and finish at 1am the following day

Comment: You need to post you table structure / sql for create table, that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TeacherName, SUM(Hours), SUM(Rate) FROM TABLE GROUP BY TeacherName
```

I don't think you can query that detailed part where you show the booked classes unless you are going to add some functions on the html part.

Edit ---------------------

Try this

```html
<?php
 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost', 'root', '');

 $sel = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM db_try.TeachersBooking");

 $cnt = 0;
 $TeacherName = "";
 $arrData = array();
 while ($row = $sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  if($TeacherName != $row['TeacherName'])
  {
   $cnt = 0;
  }

  $TeacherName = $row['TeacherName'];
  $arrData[$TeacherName][$cnt]['TeacherName'] = $row['TeacherName'];
  $arrData[$TeacherName][$cnt]['Date'] = $row['Date'];
  $arrData[$TeacherName][$cnt]['start_time'] = $row['start_time'];
  $arrData[$TeacherName][$cnt]['end_time'] = $row['end_time'];
  $arrData[$TeacherName][$cnt]['hour'] = $row['hour'];
  $arrData[$TeacherName][$cnt]['rate'] = $row['rate'];

 $cnt++;
 }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <table cellspacing="20">
  <tr>
   <th>No</th>
   <th>Teacher's Name</th>
   <th>Date</th>
   <th>Class start time</th>
   <th>Class end time</th>
   <th>Hours</th>
   <th>Rate</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
  $count = 1;
   foreach ($arrData as $key => $Teacher) {
    $TeacherRate = $TeacherHours = 0;

    foreach ($Teacher as $key => $row) {
     echo "<tr>
       <td>".$count."</td>
       <td>".$row['TeacherName']."</td>
       <td>".$row['Date']."</td>
       <td>".$row['start_time']."</td>
       <td>".$row['end_time']."</td>
       <td>".$row['hour']."</td>
       <td>".$row['rate']."</td>
      </tr>";

    $TeacherHours += $row['hour'];
    $TeacherRate += $row['rate'];
    $count++;
    }

    echo "<tr>
       <td colspan='5'>Total</td>
       <td>".$TeacherHours."</td>
       <td>".$TeacherRate."</td>
      </tr>";
   }

  ?>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Group by is not working in my case because when i use group by it returns only one row of that particular teacher

Comment: Thanks for you answer but when i add it to jquery datatable output is not properly shown after removing colspan because datatable does not supports colspan.

Answer (score 0):

Although, it will be a whole lot easier thing if you would've declared the start_time and end_time as date time.

In the below line of code I had to change the string in normal time format and then perform the basic summation of time:

```
SELECT TeacherName, SUM(Rate) 
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC
(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`date`, ' ',
REPLACE(`end_time`, '.', '')), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p'), STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`date`, ' ',
REPLACE(`start_time`, '.', '')), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p'))
)
)
) AS tot_time
FROM teachers
GROUP BY TeacherName
```